# What is the equivalent of Python's itertools.product in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, arrays, python-itertools

I'm looking for a method that has the same effect as Python's `itertools.product` in Ruby. Take the following Python code:

```
from itertools import product

chars = []
for i in range(97,123):
    chars.append(chr(i))

for a in range(1,3):
    for i in product(chars,repeat=a):
        s = ''.join(i)
        print s
```

That outputs something like this:

```
a, b, c... x, y, z, aa, ab, ac... ax, ay, az, ba, bb, bc.. etc.
```

I tried to translate that into Ruby:

```
(1..2).each do |n|
  ('a'..'z').to_a.combination(n).each do |c|
    s = c.join
    puts s
  end
end
```

But the output isn't the same. The one-character ones work fine (a-z), but when it goes into two-character ones, it doesn't work as I expected:

```
ab, ac, ad.. ax, ay, az, bc, bd, be
```

It isn't generating `aa`, `ba` or `bb` - so it appears it's generating all the combinations without repeating characters or something?

So what method should I use to generate *all* the combinations like `itertools.product` does in Python?

Comment: The key difference between `Array#product` and `itertools.product` is that Ruby's is a method instead of a function. That's usually an inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write (simplified for 3 elements, Ruby 1.9 required):

```
xs = ["a", "b", "c"]
strings = 1.upto(xs.size).flat_map do |n| 
  xs.repeated_permutation(n).map(&:join)
end
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "aa", "ab", "ac", ...,  "cca", "ccb", "ccc"]
```

A lazy solution: you could easily write it with `each`s instead of `map`s, but let's check  "lazy" from Ruby 2.0:

```
xs = ("a".."z").to_a
strings = 1.upto(xs.size).lazy.flat_map do |n| 
  xs.repeated_permutation(n).lazy.map(&:join)
end
```

Comment: works great, but is there any way to make this a generator? - using it with 6 character a-z strings takes up all my RAM!

Comment: For a lazy solution: 1) Use each instead of maps. 2) Taste the lazy pattern that's coming in Ruby 2.0: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/1803/lazy.rb. Add lazy before flat_map and map, and then each the expression.

Answer (score 3):

You have [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product) which is like [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work - could you give an example that gives the same output as my Python code?

Comment: Using the example given on itertools.product docs (_product('ABCD', 'xy')_) in Ruby could be something like _%w{ A B C D }.product(%w{ x y }).map(&:join)_

Comment: I mean using a repeat - like in my Python example, `product(chars,repeat=a)` (a is 1, then 2) - what if you wanted to generate every 5 character combination? - in Python you would do `product(chars,repeat=5)` - how can you do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Magic (not very pretty though):

```
a = ('a'..'z').to_a
result = (0..2).map { |n| 
  a.product(*n.times.inject([]) { |s,x| s << a }) }.map { |x| x.map(&:join) } 
}

puts result
```

Explanation: in order to work as the python `product` you need to repeat the array `n-1` times in the `product` arguments.

So `product('abc', repeat=n)` is the same in ruby as:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
a.product()     # n = 1
a.product(a)    # n = 2
a.product(a, a) # n = 3
```

That's what the nasty `inject` does in the above code. It builds such an "argument array" automatically. It's not very efficient code though, so don't try to build large "products" with it.

Comment: Thanks! - so it looks like there is no built-in equivalent to Python's `repeat` argument then?

Comment: @AlexCoplan No, no direct equivalent that I could find at least in the std library.

Comment: @AlexCoplan However with `a.product(*[a]*n)` you get pretty close. Where `n` equivalent to the `repeat=n` in python.

Comment: There is Array#repeated_combination.

Comment: @steenslag - not quite the same, see my comment on your answer.

Comment: should have been `repeated_permutation`. Tokland has it now.

Answer (score 1):

After I wrote this, I noticed Casper's solution which is essentially the same. Some might find this one more readable so I am leaving it..

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']

p (0..2).inject([]) { |acc, a|
  acc + arr.product(*[arr]*a).map(&:join)
}

=> ["a", "b", "c", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc", "ca", "cb", "cc", "aaa", "aab", "aac", "aba", "abb", "abc", "aca", "acb", "acc", "baa", "bab", "bac", "bba", "bbb", "bbc", "bca", "bcb", "bcc", "caa", "cab", "cac", "cba", "cbb", "cbc", "cca", "ccb", "ccc"]
```

Key "gotchas" would be

- `*[arr]*a`, which first creates an array of `a` `arr`s, then splats it into `a` arguments of `product` method.
- `map(&:join)`, which is a shorthand for `map{|e| e.join}`
- `inject` (aka "reduce", from "map-reduce" fame), one of the FP pillars

Comment: Nice one. Much better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, Array#product results in a Cathesian product. Adding the original array would yield the same results.

```
ar = (?a..?z).to_a
ar + ar.product(ar).map(&:join)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of tokland, I've got it:

```
(1..2).each do |n|
  ('a'..'z').to_a.repeated_permutation(n).each do |a|
    s = a.join
    puts s
  end
end
```

And it's lazy, so it doesn't hog RAM when you're using it to generate longer strings.